# DDD/CQRS confusion regarding ReadModels and the Domain

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, cqrs

So after much reading I've now come to the realization that complex reporting functions do not belong in your typical Repository and that there needs to be some kind of dedicated "Finder" which returns read only objects to be used in reporting.

What I'm unclear on is where the "Finder" classes, as well as their associated ReadModel classes are supposed to go inside my project? Are the finders like repositories in that you have an interface for the finder inside the infrastructure assembly along with concrete Readmodels?

Where do these classes belong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually have a logical query 'layer'.  Logical since I do not always need to have it separated into its own assembly (from a .Net/C# perspective).  It should not be in your domain since the domain should not be querying IMHO.  The domain is concerned with aggregates, entities, value objects and the like.  Anything else it needs would need to be fed into the domain objects.  The querying bit probably comes into play more on the application service edge.

What I then end up with is my repositories returning only the required full aggregates / entities and a separate `IQuery` interface implemented on the read side.  Typically I have it in a `DataAccess` assembly.  For instance:

```
public interface IUserQuery
{
    bool ContainsEMail(string emailAddress);
    int NumberOfAdminisitrators();
    DataRow Profile(Guid id);
    DataTable FriendRequests(Guid id);
    SomeReadModel ForSomethingThatContainsSayAList(DateTime date);
}
```

You will notice that I use simple types if I can and technology specific data access objects like `DataRow`, `DataTable`, *never* `DataSet` :) --- although `DataSet` *may* be used for composite data but it is somewhat cumbersome.

I try to keep specific read models (DTOs) to a minimum but every once in a while they may be required when dealing with composite data.

Comment: Ok so rather than having an IEnumerable of UserInfo classes returned from your UserQuery, you will actually return DataRows? May I ask what your reason behind this is? Would it not be wise to have a UserInfo class living inside the domain which your UserQuery can populate and return. In theory this would shield any code which depends on your UserQuery class from potential changes the database engine/framework used below?

Comment: The query layer is supposed to be a very lightweight implementation.  If you are happy with the extra overhead of mapping another class that is fine also.  There really is no "right" or "wrong" here.  You will need to do what you are comfortable with.  But changes in the database lead to changes *somewhere* anyway :)

Comment: Eben thank you for your answers to my questions, you pointed me in the right direction and it helped me immensely.